# Visio 2013 Geocoding?

Tags: geolocation, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm pretty new to Visio other than doing some quick not that advanced diagrams. How ever i have a project where we want to map out all of our building locations, and I was wonder how/if you can use geolocations in Visio. I can successfully connect to the database and retrieve the needed info, but I do not see how to use the lat and long to map a point.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Visio isn't a mapping program its a charting program, why would it care about Long. and Lat.?   What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Where exactly are you getting stuck implementing your solution?  Perhaps you should be considering [Microsoft's MapPoint](http://www.microsoft.com/mappoint/en-us/home.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

To add additional data to diagrams, you need to add the data to the objects as additional fields.

Go to the Data tab and show the shape data window. Then you can add two entries for separate lat/long or a single combined entry. You can define shape data sets for your diagram so all shapes get the same data or manually add the fields. Either way, right-clicking over the shape data window should show you the way.

Of course that only allows you to associate the data with a shape. It will not, as @techie007 infers, get you a map.

In Visio, the only way to produce such a map is likely to be to get a map bitmap and use it as a background then manually position your shapes. Although it is *possible* to try to automate this, it is likely to be a difficult job - there are not that many people who really understand Visio automation.

---

Personally, when I want to do the task you've outlined, I turn to one of the many geomapping tools available online. These take CSV or Excel data with latitude and longitude data and produce a Google, Bing or similar map with appropriate flags. You can also do this directly from a Google database (see Google Drive).

As you seem to have access to Office 2013, you might also want to check out the PowerMap addin for Excel which is a free download from Microsoft. It will take a table of data in and Excel sheet and map it for you using Bing maps.